# Get current axes from motion_notify_event

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot that contains multiple subplots. Each subplot has different data. I am also catching the motion_notify_event with the intention of displaying data labels on hover. How can I capture the current subplot axes from the event?

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def on_move(event):
    if event.inaxes is not None:
        # Which subplot am I hovering over?
        pass

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (0, 0), colspan=3)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (1, 0), colspan=3, rowspan=3)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (1, 3), rowspan=3)

ax1.plot(random.sample(xrange(100), 10), random.sample(xrange(100), 10), 'ro')
ax2.plot(random.sample(xrange(100), 10), random.sample(xrange(100), 10), 'bo')
ax3.plot(random.sample(xrange(100), 10), random.sample(xrange(100), 10), 'go')

on_move_id = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

`event` is an instance of [LocationEvent](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.LocationEvent), thus`event.inaxes`  contains already the subplot axes. Just try:

```
def on_move(event):
    if event.inaxes is not None:
        x = event.xdata
        y = event.ydata
        event.inaxes.plot(x,y,'ro')
        event.canvas.draw()
```